# Facebook Link is not opening on facebook app

Tags: ios, facebook, plist, ios9.1

This question have been asked before but there is no solution for `iOS9`. I found a solution on stackoverflow to add `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in my `.plist`. I did but still it is not opening it by default on facebook app.
[image]

I am not using any login with facebook there are some link you can say like on contact page if the facebook button taps it should take them to the facebook page. But instead of opening the facebook app it opens safari and asks for login.
**The facebook link I'm trying to open is a link to a photo album to a page.**

Comment: Would you like an answer in `Swift` or `Objective C`?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to do the following:

1. Replace the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` values from your `info.plist` file with just one - `fb`
2. Run the following code when the link is clicked

**Swift**:

```
let fbURL = NSURL(string: "fb://album?id=<YOUR ALBUM ID HERE>")!
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(fbURL) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(fbURL)
}
```

**Objective-C**:

```
NSURL* fbURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"fb://album?id=<YOUR ALBUM ID HERE>"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:fbURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:fbURL];
}
```